# How to override Selenium Headless user agent for chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, browser

I have the following code

```
import sys
from os import path
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class DDDDDD(object):
    def __init__(self, date=None, path_to_save=None, chomedriver_exe_path=None, pred=True):
        self.pred = pred
        if chomedriver_exe_path is None:
            home = os.path.expanduser('~')
            self.chomedriver_exe_path = home + '/Downloads/chromedriver.exe'
        else:
            self.chomedriver_exe_path = chomedriver_exe_path
        self.driver = None

    def setup_driver(self):
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36'
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("headless") # --headless
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36')
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
        chrome_driver = self.chomedriver_exe_path
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver)
        return self.driver


ddddd = DDDDDD()
ddddd.setup_driver()

ddddd.driver.get("http://kluge.in-chemnitz.de/tools/browser.php")

ddddd.driver.save_screenshot('browser.png')
```

I am trying to override the user agent so this particular site I am trying to visit a banking (automate personal transaction data downloads). I have tried the following solutions.

[source 1](http://tarunlalwani.com/post/selenium-change-user-agent-different-browsers/)
[source 2](https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/)

None seem to work. The screenshot from a test site i used contains the word headless. Could someone help me do this for the chrome browser? Other browser solutions are definitely acceptable but I would prefer the chrome browser.

Comment: --headless and headless give the same result.

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me (MacOS). Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks, and `--user-agent=...` works for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

This works using Java. You might try it out the same logic with Python. I think Python has browser.execute_script.

The extension used is Chrome ModHeader extension.

```
String userAgent = PropertyReader.readItem("USER-AGENT");
String xmsisdn = PropertyReader.readItem("X-MSISDN");
String xUPSUBNO = PropertyReader.readItem("xUPSUBNO");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File(PropertyReader.readItem("CHROMEEXT")));

options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Path\\chromedriver.exe");

//Launch the Browser 

webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options); 

// set the context on the extension so the localStorage can be accessed 

webDriver.get("chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/icon.png");

// setup ModHeader with name and value
JavascriptExecutor js;
((JavascriptExecutor)webDriver).executeScript(
"localStorage.setItem('profiles', JSON.stringify([{                " +
"  title: 'Selenium', hideComment: true, appendMode: '',           " +
"  headers: [                                                      " +
"    {enabled: true, name: 'User-Agent', value: '"+userAgent+"', comment: ''}, " +
"    {enabled: true, name: 'X-UP-SUBNO', value: '"+xUPSUBNO+"', comment: ''}  " +
"  ],                                                              " +
"  respHeaders: [],                                                " +
"  filters: []                                                     " +
"}]));
```